# bitbake recipe pulling from pypi runs into timeout

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a recipe to build [aiohttp-pydantic](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp-pydantic/) from pypi which essentially looks like this (omitting license, author, summary, etc.)

```
PYPI_PACKAGE = "aiohttp-pydantic"

inherit pypi setuptools3

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "\
    python3-aiohttp \
    python3-pydantic \
"
```

Unfortunately the fetcher times out. I also tried `PYPI_PACKAGE = "aiohttp_pydantic"` with the same result.

Apart from that I also tried building directly from github source. Unfortunately, here it is attempted to import `aiohttp` for unknown reasons:

```
|   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
|   File "/build/build/tmp-orange-pi-zero/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3-aiohttp-pydantic/1.0+gitAUTOINC+69fb553635-r0/git/aiohttp_pydantic/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
|     from .view import PydanticView
|   File "/build/build/tmp-orange-pi-zero/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3-aiohttp-pydantic/1.0+gitAUTOINC+69fb553635-r0/git/aiohttp_pydantic/view.py", line 6, in <module>
|     from aiohttp.abc import AbstractView
| ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'
| ERROR: 'python3 setup.py build ' execution failed.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Execution of '/build/build/tmp-orange-pi-zero/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3-aiohttp-pydantic/1.0+gitAUTOINC+69fb553635-r0/temp/run.do_compile.18942' failed with exit code 1
```

I remember I had an issue when trying to build a python project that comes with a `pyproject.toml`. Could that be an issue here as well?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you've hit a corner case, this is a limitation but not from bitbake or the Yocto Project, rather from the maintainers of the package `aiohttp-pydantic`, it seems they arent providing the sources for that package (which is what bitbake tries to fetch), they're only providing binaries via wheel.

This can be tested by pip by using the `--no-binary` argument:

```
$ python -m pip install aiohttp-pydantic --no-binary :all:           

https://pypi.org/simple
https://pypi.org/pypi
https://test.pypi.org/simple
https://test.pypi.org/pypi
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aiohttp-pydantic (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for aiohttp-pydantic
```

Doing the same for a package that provides sources:

```
$ python -m pip install aiohttp --no-binary :all:                         

https://pypi.org/simple
https://pypi.org/pypi
https://test.pypi.org/simple
https://test.pypi.org/pypi
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting aiohttp
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5a/86/5f63de7a202550269a617a5d57859a2961f3396ecd1739a70b92224766bc/aiohttp-3.8.1.tar.gz#sha256=fc5471e1a54de15ef71c1bc6ebe80d4dc681ea600e68bfd1cbce40427f0b7578
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5a/86/5f63de7a202550269a617a5d57859a2961f3396ecd1739a70b92224766bc/aiohttp-3.8.1.tar.gz
  Downloading aiohttp-3.8.1.tar.gz (7.3 MB)
Downloading %s aiohttp-3.8.1.tar.gz (7.3 MB)
```

also we can look at the index of PyPi, for aiohttp we see the .tar.gz files:
https://pypi.org/simple/aiohttp/

but they're not present for aiohttp-pydantic

https://pypi.org/simple/aiohttp-pydantic/

You still should be able to create a recipe for that package though, but instead of using the `pypi` class you need to do it via the `pip_install_wheel` class

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I copied the `pip_install_wheel` to my own branch as this has been introduced just a few days ago and it's not yet back ported to `dunfell`. I received a two different errors: `[...]/aiohttp_pydantic-1.12.1-*.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist` and `pip._internal.exceptions.InvalidWheelFilename: aiohttp_pydantic-1.12.1-*.whl is not a valid wheel filename.` where I guess the latter is a side-effect of the first as the filename is actually available, checking the wheels on pypi.org but I'm not sure. Do I need other classes to back-port that class?THX

Comment: Can't remember for sure but I believe this was being caused by pip looking for the built .whl file in the wrong directory, take a look at:
https://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/commit/?id=efcbd827a43d7ae8962ed620b0eac9f5273b3060

You may need to do something similar, in that case it was building the .whl file inside ${S}/dist, but check what it looks like for your recipe and adapt it accordingly

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the issue. The `fetch`ing stage doesn't complain so, I guess it fetched something but I can't seem to find the wheel file. Do you know where this is supposed to be located? Besides `pip_install_wheel` do I have to inherit any other class or is this the only one?

Comment: I dont know where it might be getting built, I would poke around the ${WORKDIR} to see where the .whl file is and then set it on the recipe like that commit in meta-openembedded is doing